# Why adding the display property does not work on some part of a file, while it works on other parts?

Tags: org-mode, text-properties

Let's say I have an org file with this content (this is the Org Manual):

```
    *** System-wide header arguments
    #+vindex: org-babel-default-header-args
```

The file is opened normally, highlighted and everything.

Now, as a test I try to add a display property to the S character of System:

```
    (put-text-property (point) (1+ (point)) 'display "aaa")
```

It works. The S is replaced with aaa.

But if I try the same on a character on the vindex line then nothing happens.

Why is that?

Comment: Even if it is not obvious at the first glance. This question is directly related to Orgmode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text property is removed by `font-lock` in `org-mode` buffers.

The list `org-font-lock-extra-keywords` contains the function `org-fontify-meta-lines-and-blocks` as a matcher of a font lock keyword for meta lines, i.e., lines starting with `#+` followed by a keyword.

That function calls `org-fontify-meta-lines-and-blocks-1` which has the following lines for lines matching `#+` at the beginning:

```el
(t ;; just any other in-buffer setting, but not indented
      (org-remove-flyspell-overlays-in (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0))
      (remove-text-properties (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0)
                  '(display t invisible t intangible t))
      (add-text-properties beg (match-end 0)
                   '(font-lock-fontified t face org-meta-line))
      t)
```

One of the text properties removed there is the `display` property.

Comment: Thanks. It's a bit strange org removes properties, because it prevents other packages, minor modes from modifying the org buffer's appearance. Org should only deal with adding its own stuff and not touching anything else.

Comment: @Tom: A priori, I agree. Perhaps there is some special consideration that led to this exceptional behavior. If no one speaks to that here then you might want to ask about it on an Org mailing list.

Answer (score 2):

This complements the answer given by @Tobias, where it is explained how org-mode removes the `display` property.

One way to get around this is to use the variable `char-property-alias-alist`. It is used by Emacs to make one property to behave like another property. If you add `(display my-display)` to this list, you can set the property `my-display` on text and it would not be removed by org-mode.

The following is from the built-in documentation:

> Alist of alternative properties for properties without a value.
>   Each element should look like (PROPERTY ALTERNATIVE1 ALTERNATIVE2...).
>   If a piece of text has no direct value for a particular property, then
>   this alist is consulted.  If that property appears in the alist, then
>   the first non-nil value from the associated alternative properties is
>   returned.